# Pass/Save data from service onReceive method

Tags: android

I have service that listen for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` and I want to be able to pass(to my activity) or save(for later use in my activity) this received data. I tried Shared Preferences but it did not helped.

Maybe you are able to help save or pass received data.

**EDITED**

```
@Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());

//              /* Broadcast Receiver for battery stats                                               */
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);


        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int isCharging = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
                if (isCharging==0){

                }
                else{
                    appPrefs.setIsCharging(isCharging);
                    Log.e("inFFFF","FFFF "+appPrefs.getIsCharging()); // here I get my default value, not isCharging value

                }
            }

        };

        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
      }
```

In AppPrefs file:

```
 public void setIsCharging(int text){
             prefsEditor.putInt("isCharging", text);
         }

         public int getIsCharging(){
             return appSharedPrefs.getInt("isCharging", 9);
         }
```

Comment: What code you tried to save data in sharedPreferences. Can you post the code here.

Comment: `int isCharging = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);`
`appPrefs.setIsCharging(isCharging);` to set it

Comment: post your code for more details

Comment: post the code of `AppPreferences` class and read my answer...

Comment: Thank you all for support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is not saving in `sharedPreferences` because you did not commit it.

```
public void setIsCharging(int text){
    prefsEditor.putInt("isCharging", text);
    prefsEditor.commit();  //Add this line to commit data in sharedPreferences.
}
```

Comment: :D My mistake, ... I feel silly. Thank you very much. Forgot to add commit at the end. Answer will be accepted in 2min(stackoverflow restrictions)